# Heroku SSL Websocket communication

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am trying to get working my node js application on heroku. this time I fixed all of the issues but one which can be fixed two ways:

1. Is it possible to make heroku serve my application on classic http://... not the https://... ?

if not then

2. When I am trying to connect to the ws://gofishy.heroku.com it says this

   `VM153:35 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gofishy.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'gofishy.heroku.com'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.`

and this

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

I am trying to connect like this:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + server);
```

where `server = 'gofishy.herokuapp.com'` and on the server I have this:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server });
```

can I pass something to `new WebsocketServer` as an argument to make it work over the SSL?

Answer (score 3):

I should have done this:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://" + server);
```

instead of this:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + server);
```

notice the `wss` with two `s`.

Comment: How does your backend looks like?